# Embedded node/javascript sandbox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sandbox, v8

I'm writing a Node app that allows users to execute arbitrary javascript code - sort of an "internal API" / business flow that extends beyond the regular UI.

I'm looking for a sandbox environment that offers the following:

- Separate execution without spawning an entirely new thread - this would be run by thousands of users, I'd prefer to stick with anonymous functions that have no access to the parent call stack... OR... in the event of threads... the ability to spawn across multiple servers.
- Syntax checking that throws Exceptions on parse/exec errors vs. crashing the entire app.
- The ability to disable functions/var access. I'm trying to prevent access to Node's I/O... so a user can't turn this into a DoS script or read /etc/passwd, but can run any native syntax and a list of pre-approved functions.
- Timeout control... so an execution ceiling can apply to  `while(true) do_intensive_stuff();`, etc.

Any obvious choices spring to mind?

Comment: Do the built-in methods not work for this?  http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html  I haven't tested them myself, but they seem like a good option for you, at least to get started with.  You may be able to wrap your extra features around them easily.

Comment: Good suggestion, but doesn't look mature enough right now... according to the docs: "Stability: 2 - Unstable"

Comment: The stability indicator is referring to the API.  In other words, the API may change later on for newer versions of Node.  http://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html It does not indicate that a particular part of Node shouldn't be used in production.  For that, I'd suggest looking at their bug tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google for 'node js sandbox' and you'll get a few hits of projects of various age and maturity.

http://gf3.github.com/sandbox/ seems to be popular.

Comment: This seems like the closest yet!

Comment: Note: gf3 sandbox can be broken out of.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1: use [js.js](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js/) interpreter. Solves sandboxing, but does nod solve timeout control.

solution 2: have pool of sandboxed worker node.js processes (each in its own chroot or separate vm environment), communicating via tcp socket/dnode/your own rpc. Input tasks wait in the queue, if execution limit is hit whole process is killed and respawned, if not it is reused for the next task. That way you are not limited by single machine and can easily scale horizontally.

Also try to check how workers are implemented in [travis-ci](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. js.js seems to be a full-scale interpreter - I'd prefer to stick to native V8 if possible for speed. A collection of sandbox'd worker nodes is safe and seems good for scalability, but would it still expose Node funcs? I'm trying to limit all access to global objects, with the exception of read-only functions exposed via an API object, so code needs to be written within the confines of my defined API.

Answer (score 0):

There's another module that can do the job - [vm2](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2). Unlike `sandbox` it allows you to securly run untrusted code with whitelisted built-in node objects.